# Service to service authentication using Azure AD and WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, azure-active-directory, adal

Ive created a .NET core web app which is using Azure AD for the identity. This is all working fine as expected and anything I decorate using [Authroize] is protected.

I am now wanting to secure one of my API controllers to be accessible from an external service.

I followed this tutorial which explains service-service authentication.

[Service to service auth with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service)

Using this I have managed to request a token

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANTID}/oauth2/token
grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id={CLIENTID}
&client_secret={CLIENTSECRET}
&resource=https%3A%2F%mydirectory.onmicrosoft.com/myappname
```

Running this with postman, I get the Bearer access_token so looks good.

Now if I call my web app in Postman with this bearer token on the header,

```
GET https://localhost:44392/api/booking
Authorization Bearer {access_token}
```

I get a HTML response from one the Microsoft dialogues. So it seems it is just going into the redirect loop, so I am now confused on whether I have a configuration problem in the token request, or whether my web app needs to be setup in a different way. The article here mentions something about permissions in the manifest file, but I am confused why this would be necessary?

[enter link description here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/12/secure-asp-net-web-api-2-azure-active-directory-owin-middleware-adal/)

[image]

Some additional points

- My web app and the POST for the token use the same AD ClientID
- I tried different AD Apps for each feature (Web and Service-to-Service) but didnt seem to make any difference
- If I just perform a standard login on the browser, the API endpoint resolves as expected.

Any assistance appreciated!

### Updates:

I managed to try the Daemon .NET 4.5 app and this worked flawlessly using the UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerToken

[Daemon Service to service auth on .NET 4.5](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon)

However in my .NET Core app, this middleware isn't available so I tried using JwtBearer middleware but I still get the login prompt.

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                Audience = "https://localhost:44392",
                Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANTNAME}.onmicrosoft.com"
            });
```

As you can see, I have only set 2 properties in the BearerOptions but I believe they should have been enough to [Authorize] my API endpoint.

Comment: Can you help clarify what specific step in the process you are getting stuck? It seems like you have successfully registered a client and resource application. It also seems like you have successfully acquired an access token for your resource. Are you having trouble having your resource accept the token?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly where I am stuck. I would have assumed that as the same clientID is setup in the web app, the access_token would be accepted. It actually might be accepted, but the problem is that it is not performing a 'headless' authorization, which is leading me to believe that I must have something wrong somewhere?

Comment: Are you using some middle-ware to validate the token? What is the specific error that your web API is throwing?

Comment: Just using the standard OpenIDConnectAuthentication middleware which the File > New Project > Use AD Identity sets up. The actual problem is that it is causing a redirect to the Microsoft login page, rather than using the valid access_token. Im wondering if I have requested the wrong grant_type or something along those lines?

Answer (score 0):

> POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{CLIENTID}/oauth2/token

First the token point is incorrect when you acquire the token, we should use `tenantId` instead of `clientId`.

And to troubleshoot this issue, I suggest that you decode the access_token from [this site](https://jwt.io/) to see whether the `aud` claim in the token is same as `Audience` you config in the web API project.

Comment: You are right - that was a mistake in my post above which I have edited so I actually was using TENANTID.

Interestingly the aud I receive back looks correct but when I actually browse to it, its not found? Its in the format of https://{DIRNAME}.onmicrosoft.com/{APPNAME}

Can you advise?

Comment: Just noticed that the JWT verification site says Invalid Signature?

What do you refer to when you mention Audience? Is this the App ID URI?

Comment: Also, Im seeing some older samples mentioning UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication but I cant seem to access this in .NET Core

Comment: The invalid signature is because that you doesn't provide the public key to validate the signature. The **audience** (`https://localhost:44392`) you config in the web API is not matched with the value in the token(`https://{DIRNAME}.onmicrosoft.com/{APPNAME}`). You need to config the value of `aud` claim(`https://{DIRNAME}.onmicrosoft.com/{APPNAME}`) to your web API project.

Comment: Where would I get the public key? I can see my token is in 3 parts so I thought one part was the key? (Sorry, newbie at this)

In my directory, I do have the reply url of https://localhost:44392 added already.

How do I config the claim? Do you have any code samples as this works fine with UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication (so I think my directory and app config is fine) but doesnt seem to work with the newer libraries?

Comment: This issue is not relative to the public key. We are not able to config the **Claim** which is issued from identity provider like Azure AD. We just need to ensure that the **audience** configuration in the web API project could match the `aud` claim in the token. When we acquire the token, we need to provider the resource parameter which will be issued as the `aud` claim in the access token. And you can refer the [code sample](https://github23.com/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore.git) here about secure the web API for .Net core.

Comment: I have managed to get the token , is there any way or url though which I can decrypt the token to get client_id