# Service to Service REST call from Wordpress to .NET WebAPI secured with Azure AD

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, asp.net-web-api, active-directory

I am currently creating a .NET Core WebAPI secured with Azure AD. (Which is also giving me challenges [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667486/service-to-service-authentication-using-azure-ad-and-webapi)

I want to call this API from a Wordpress website but need to do a headless service-to-service call. So I need to get an access_token from azure ad (using my active directory app) and send this as the Bearer token.

I've had a look around for PHP samples but nothing concrete has come up so far, so would be great to get some pointers or samples on this.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you can custom PHP script in your WP application to acquire access token via `client credentials` flow.

For the detailed steps, you can refer to [Call Microsoft Graph in a service or daemon app](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/app_only) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code for basic concepts.

And you can refer to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-php-graphapi-web/blob/master/PHP/AuthorizationHelperForGraph.php for the PHP sample functionality in the similar scenario.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I understand this would allow access to the MS graph, but would the bearer token generated by the client credentials flow still grant access to my webapi though (protected by [Authorize]) or would their be additional setup required on my webapi to allow this? (This overlaps with my other question I am still battling with if you could help on that too!)

Comment: the access token generated by `client credentials` is a standard JWT token which has the permissions of your application in AAD. You can set it in request Authorization header to access your web app.

Comment: Do you have any code samples of this actually working? See my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667486/service-to-service-authentication-using-azure-ad-and-webapi which I am trying to do this with a webapp and webapi in the same project and am getting nowhere.

Comment: Actually, the repository I provided in the answer, is a workable sample in PHP, but your new question seems that you require an asp.net sample. You can try to refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples#server-or-daemon-application-to-web-api for the samples

Comment: Im already aware of the samples. The issues is when you have a web AND an api controller in the same project, none of the samples work or cover this scenario.

Comment: If your webapi application is set Authorization feature in Azure App Service and protected by AAD, we don't have to modify it. We need to implement AAD SDK or functionalities in the web application which need to call the application under AAD.

Comment: Im not using app service, I need to do this within the app itself ideally.

Comment: To your original question, what you want to know is how to get a server-to-server access token against AzureAD in PHP, or how to verify the token in a backed asp.net application?